# How to crop images with the Blocks module?

Tags: module, crop, blocks

I was wondering if there's a module/add-on around which lets me crop/resize images with the [Blocks](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/blocks) module?

Answer (score 0):

you may try https://buzzingpixel.com/software/ansel-ee it works with blocks and has really cool functions.